# Prefix client's name to domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, website, web-applications

I have a product registered on godaddy having website-name abc.xyz.com, when someone registers on my website, I want to generate a website for him by name username.abc.com.

How can I achieve this, which record I need to setup in my dns.

This feature is implemented by many site, for example when I registered on https://www.zendesk.com/ by name- "username" . They created https://username.zendesk.com/ for me.

Here is a slight change in my requirement instead of www.zendesk.com I have something like www.product1.zendesk.com and I want  username.product1.com to be generated
instead of username.zendesk.com

I am using ruby on rails for the web development. And I need to generate the website instantly and it also should not take any time to propagate throughout the internet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate a little bit more on what software you use(DNS server, etc.) and what exactly you need help with then.

Comment: @mkzero Do I need a name server(software) at my end to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, you have to have and be able to **manage** DNS-server and Web-server

Answer (score 1):

If it should take no time to propagate, your best option is probably to have a wildcard DNS entry for `*.product1.com` preconfigured, as DNS changes can take up to 48h(and longer) until they are propagated through all caches.

With this wildcard DNS you will need a configuration for your webserver, that can handle multiple hosts, as well. So everything points to *.product1.com and your webserver(or loadbalancing proxy) decides, depending on the submitted hostname, which site will be delivered to the client.

Comment: how my web server will decide which website should be delivered to the client.

Comment: That greatly depends on your webserver. You should read the manual to your webserver for that matter.